# Removing the empty values from the array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array which i have extracted from html using DOM. Now as the below array shows there are many empty data which i dont want. So wenever i try to remove the empty values from the array its not removed.

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => Outpost Congratulations13 [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] =>
 [7] => Yard will reflect the type of work that they do and the strength and variety of their membership, from recent graduates to emerging and mid-career artists. 
[8] => [9] => [10] => [11] => Gallery  Closed Good Friday, open Bank Holiday Monday. Admission Free 
[12] => [13] => K  Yard, Castle Street 
[14] => [15] => Friday 1 Mar 3 [16] => [17] => [18] => [19] => www.somesite.co.uk 
[20] => [21] => [22] => [23] => Map [24] => [25] => Contact the Organiser Tell a Friend about this Event [26] => [27] => Plan Your Journey [28] => [29] => [30] => )
```

What all i have tried:-

1. array_filter : It did nt work.
2. Many functions to check whether the value is empty or not still did not work.
3. I tried to use strlen to find the length of empty strings , But it shows 22, 2 30 as the lenght.
4. I use str_replace to replace spaces with ntg still nt working and stlen is showing 22, 28,etc for empty values.
5. I have used trim bt no use...

Can anyone help me out as to why the strlen of a data is 22 or more. And how to remove these type of elements from array???

Comment: array_filter with no other parameters $x=array_filter($x); http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: YUp i tried , still the same result

Comment: Could you make the code available in codepad?

Comment: Could you post the array as PHP code so we can copy and paste, please?

Comment: are you sure they are empty? do a var_dump(); instead - __If no callback is supplied, all entries of input equal to FALSE (see converting to boolean) will be removed.__

Comment: if i use var_dump() its showing  [0]=> string(22) " "

Comment: Yes waygood no data at all....its showing empty string

Comment: Where does the array come from? Are you creating it via a file() read - if so, check the FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES flag (and FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES as well)

Comment: An empty string with length of 22 is highly suspicious; could you `echo bin2hex($arr[0])`?

Comment: Jack if i use bin2hex($arr[0]), its showing output as 0d0a2020202020202020202020202020202020202020

Comment: @MarkBaker I am parsing the html file and getting data from it into the array

Comment: So how are you `parsing` the html file? How do you get this array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since the data has empty strings (22 spaces etc) we need to trim them

```
$emptyRemoved = array_filter($myArray, 'trim');
```

Comment: Nope i tried it long back did nt work..........i already mentioned above, trim, str_replace....none worked

Comment: +1. Judging from the hex output, this is most likely the right answer :)

Comment: That'll remove `string(1) "0"` as well, though.

Comment: Thats why I +1'd your answer

Comment: +2 from my side..................Almost perfect, But still 2 extra elements are there

Comment: +2 from my side..................Almost perfect, But still 2 extra elements are there

Comment: Waygood 12 records hav vanished thanks to u but still 2 records are der which r empty.......

Comment: @Jack says there are some dodgy characters in there too, use MichaelRushton answer and remove those chars too

Comment: @PavanK You can apply `bin2hex()` on those strings as well to find out what characters are inside.

Comment: bin2hex() output of that chracter shows this .. 0d0a090d0a202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020200d0a2020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020203c212d2d0d0a2020202020202020202020   hahaha very funny

Comment: I am accepting this answer because its almost perfect for me , though a few problems, but thanks a lot........

Answer (score 3):

This should do what you need:

```
$array = array(
  'Hello',
  '',
  0,
  NULL,
  FALSE,
  '0',
  '    ',
);

$new_array = array_filter($array, function ($value)
{
    return strlen(trim($value));
}
);
```

This will give:

```
Array ( [0] => Hello [2] => 0 [5] => 0 )
```

The problem with using `array_filter($array)` or `array_filter($array, 'trim')` is that string/integer `0` will also be removed, which presumably isn't what you want?

Edit:

If you're using PHP < 5.3, use the following:

```
function trim_array ($value)
{
    return strlen(trim($value));
}

$new_array = array_filter($array, 'trim_array');
```

Comment: +1. This is more explicit in which string property should be evaluated :)

Comment: @MichaelRushton how can we use function within the array_filter ?? I am getting syntax error

Comment: Sorry, had a partially removed `print_r` in there before. Fixed.

Comment: Its shoeing language feature nt compatible with php....can we use the function outside >?

Comment: What version of PHP do you have?

Comment: Then it should work. Can you paste the error message you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

```
function array_remove_empty($arr){
    $narr = array();
    while(list($key, $val) = each($arr)){
        if (is_array($val)){
            $val = array_remove_empty($val);
            // does the result array contain anything?
            if (count($val)!=0){
                // yes :)
                $narr[$key] = $val;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (trim($val) != ""){
                $narr[$key] = $val;
            }
        }
    }
    unset($arr);
    return $narr;
}

array_remove_empty(array(1,2,3, '', array(), 4)) => returns array(1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: It's kinda long, but go through it.

Comment: Not sure whether recursion was really applicable here ;-)